# How to evaluate this integral - beta function?

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, beta-function

$$ \displaystyle\int\limits^{\cssId{upper-bound-mathjax}{1}}_{\cssId{lower-bound-mathjax}{0}} \left(1-\left(1-x^3\right)^\sqrt{2}\right)^\sqrt{3}x^2\,\cssId{int-var-mathjax}{\mathrm{d}x} $$

I have been taught Gamma function and Beta function recently. But I cannot evaluate this integral. I am unable to proceed. I need help with the approach.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\bbox[10px,#ffd]{\int_{0}^{1}\bracks{1 - \pars{1 - x^{3}}^{\root{2}}}^{\root{3}}x^{2}\,\dd x}
\\[5mm] \stackrel{x^{3}\ \mapsto\ y}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{1 - \pars{1 - y}^{\root{2}}}^{\root{3}}\dd y
\\[5mm]
\stackrel{1 - y\ \mapsto\ z}{=}\,\,\,&
{1 \over 3}\int_{0}^{1}
\bracks{1 - z^{\root{2}}}^{\root{3}}\dd z
\\[5mm] \,\,\,\stackrel{\pars{1 - z}^{\root{2}}\ \mapsto\ t}{=}\,\,\,&
{\root{2} \over 6}\int_{0}^{1}t^{\root{3}}\pars{1 - t}^{\root{2}/2 - 1}
\,\dd t
\\[5mm] = &\
\bbx{{\root{2} \over 6}\,\mrm{B}\pars{\root{3} + 1,{\root{2} \over 2}}}
\approx 0.1546
\end{align}

> $\ds{\mrm{B}}$ is the
> [Beta Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Beta_function).

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Try the substitution $u=(1-x^3)^\sqrt{2}$.